# Create Intermediate CA that can issue Certificates?

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, certificate, office365, smime

I'm trying to create a CA and Intermediate CA for use in Office 365 signing/encryption purposes in Outlook. I've been able to follow a bunch of tutorials and with OpenSSL produce a CA and Intermediate CA that generate certificates. I'm running into two problems:

1. When I generate an end-user x509 end-user certificate, it is flagged
   as invalid because the intermediate CA does not have authority to
   issue certificates.
2. If I instead generate the end-user certificate with the root CA, I
   can sign and encrypt emails fine, but after a while it stops
   working.

I think problem 2 is caused by the end-user certificates not being signed by the intermediate CA. In Exchange Online, the SMIMEExpiredCertificateThumbprint returns the intermediate certificate thumbprint, not the root CA. I can still publish a root CA generated end-user cert to the GAL and send a few quick emails, but once Outlook syncs with the GAL its sees the cert is not generated from the intermediate cert and declares it unauthorized.

I think solving problem 1 will solve problem 2, but I don't know how to set permissions for an intermediate CA to issue certificates. Any help?

Here's how I'm currently generating a root and intermediate CA:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out ia.key 4096
openssl req -new -key ia.key -out ia.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 730 -in ia.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -serial -out ia.crt
```

And here's how the clients are being generated:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out email.key 2048
openssl req -new -key email.key -out email.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in email.csr -CA ia.crt -CAkey ia.key -CAcreateserial -out email.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -in email.crt -inkey email.key -out email.pfx
openssl x509 -in email.crt -serial -noout >> email.meta
openssl x509 -in email.crt -fingerprint -noout  >> email.meta
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically I didn't necessarily figure out how to solve the problem with OpenSSL but found that GnuTLS prompts for certificate usage in a way that is easy to work with.

I'm generating the root CA as follows:

```
certtool --generate-privkey --bits 4096 --outfile ca.key
certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey ca.key --template ca.vars --outfile ca.crt
```

Where my ca.vars looks like:

```
organization = [Company Name]
unit = [Org Unit]
locality = [City]
state = [State]
country = [Country Code]
challenge_password = [password]
password = [password]
expiration_days = 1825
serial = 1
ca
cert_signing_key
crl_signing_key
cn = '[Company Name] Root CA 000001'
```

NOTE: The password is listed in the ca.vars file which is insecure; but for my implementation a script generates the vars file and then deletes it using the srm deletion tool. If you aren't using scripts to generate your vars files, just omit the password and challenge_password lines and you'll be prompted.

Then the intermediate CA's as follows:

```
certtool --generate-privkey --bits 4096 --outfile ia.key
certtool --generate-request --template ia.vars --load-privkey ia.key --outfile ia.csr
certtool --generate-certificate --template ia.vars --load-request ia.csr --load-ca-certificate ca.crt --load-ca-privkey ca.key  --outfile ia.crt
```

The difference between ca.vars and ia.vars is that I set the expiration days to 365 and add the following line:

```
path_len = 1
```

From there I can use the above script with openssl and the ia_[sign/encrypt] certificate authorities to generate x509 certs that I can use in Outlook with Office 365 to sign/encrypt emails. I'll paste it again just for reference:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out email.key 2048
openssl req -new -key email.key -out email.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in email.csr -CA ia.crt -CAkey ia.key -CAcreateserial -out email.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -in email.crt -inkey email.key -out email.pfx
openssl x509 -in email.crt -serial -noout >> email.meta
openssl x509 -in email.crt -fingerprint -noout  >> email.meta
```

Hope this helps someone besides me! :)